# Why am I getting a NaN is not a valid value of Int32 error?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net-3.5, asmx

UPDATE:

I am getting the same error.  When I click on the `x`, it should be returning {id: 23}, but it is returning `{id: NaN}` instead.  This problem corrects itself if I remove the ternary operator.

---

I have made a change to my webpage:

It was this:

`$( "#notifications" ).prepend( "<div class='notification' id='n" + notifications.d[i].id + "'><span class='notification_text'>" + notifications.d[i].text + "</span><a href='#' class='notification_button' id='b" + notifications.d[i].id + "' value='x'>x</a></div>" ).show();`

and I changed it to this, added a ternary condition depending on the value of `notifications.d[i].sticky`:

`$( "#notifications" ).prepend( "<div class='notification' id='n" + notifications.d[i].id + "'><span class='notification_text'>" + notifications.d[i].text + "</span>" + ( notifications.d[i].sticky ? "" : "<a href='#' class='notification_button' id='b'" + notifications.d[i].id + "' value='x'>x</a>'" ) + "</div>" ).show();`

That part works fine, it not creating the `x` link if sticky is true.

However, when I click on any other `x`, I get a serverside error message:

`NaN is not a valid value of Int32`

The serverside code looks like this:

```
[WebMethod()]
public int CloseNotification(int id) {
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"])) {
        using (command = new SqlCommand("update notifications set closed_by = @user where id = @id", connection)) {
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = id;
            command.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4).Value = "abc";

            connection.Open();
            intAffectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return intAffectedRows;
}
```

Anyone know why I am getting that error?

I'm thinking I've made a mistake with the ternary section, probably a double or single quote mistake, but I can't see it.

Comment: You haven't included any details of how CloseNotification is called.

Comment: It is basically extracting the number from the id of the `x` and sending it to the server.  Please see the update in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Syntax error in your code on the line that reads

```
id='b'" + notifications.d[i].id + "' value='x'>x</a>'" ) + "</div>" ).show();
```

There is an extra `'` after the `b`. It should read:

```
id='b" + notifications.d[i].id + "' value='x'>x</a>'" ) + "</div>" ).show();
```

**Edit**:

You also have an extra `'` at the end of your ternary operation.

```
( notifications.d[i].sticky ? "" : "<a href='#' class='notification_button' id='b" + notifications.d[i].id + "' value='x'>x</a>'" )
```

should be:

```
( notifications.d[i].sticky ? "" : "<a href='#' class='notification_button' id='b" + notifications.d[i].id + "' value='x'>x</a>" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a single quote after `</a>` in the ternary operator.